# AWS EC2 Instances in Private Subnets not receiving traffic from internet-facing NLB

Tags: amazon-web-services, nlb, private-subnet

I have an internet-facing Network Load Balancer forwarding traffic on port 3002 across 2 Availability Zones. Each AZ has at least 1 public subnet. The traffic coming to this NLB is being forwarded to a target group that contains 2 EC2 instances, each in their own private subnet. These instances have public IP's enabled and the security group for these instances is allowing all traffic on all ports. These instances have a node server running on port 3002, and the instances are considered "healthy" by the target group as expected. However, when clients are sending traffic over port 3002 to the NLB, the traffic is not reaching either EC2 instance. In another environment, I have the exact same architecture with the exception that the subnets containing the EC2 instances running the node server are public subnets and traffic is able to hit the servers as expected.

Comment: Are the target groups reporting any specific errors in the health checks? What does the security group look like for the instances?

Comment: If the health checks are successful, then the instances _are_ receiving traffic. Since the instances are in private subnets, there is zero reason to give them Public IP addresses, but it would not cause this problem. As an experiment, try replicating what works in the other environment within _this_ environment, and then figure out what is different.

Comment: @ChrisWilliams Health Checks are not failing for the servers. The Security Group that the servers belong to is accepting all traffic on all ports.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I associated the subnets containing the EC2 instances with a public route table, as they are in the other environment, and the servers began to receive traffic. The only change I made was changing the route table for the private subnets to make them public.

Comment: @jmagi98 can you enable flow logs for your EC2: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html?